# How to use lodash.debounce in nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js, lodash, debouncing

I'm trying to use `lodash.debounce` in my nuxt.js project, but I'm struggling with that.

I couldn't reproduce the Vue examples and I couldn't find a working example for Nuxt.js, so I wonder if I'm missing something bigger. Should I just use a timeout, like [this example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821337/vuetify-throttle-debounce-v-autocomplete)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue2 already has some objects with debounce properties, but it does nothing.
Vue3 is being written from scratch and will have debounce.

So there's probably nothing ready for Nuxtjs, I used the clear timeout / set timeout strategy, like the example and it worked well.